# Formula - select value based on where clause

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

I want to do a kind of localisation in Crystal Reports. For that I have defined the following table LANG:

```
Identifier    LocalisedText    LanguageCode
-------------------------------------------
1             Page             1
1             Seite            9
1             Pagina           13
2             Invoice          1
2             Rechnung         9
```

The fields `Identifier` and `LanguageCode` form my primary key.

Furthermore, I have a customer dataset table `OCRD` which has a field `LangCode` storing the language code for that customer. Thus, I joined `LANG` and `OCRD` based on the fields `LanguageCode` and `LangCode`. The screenshot below illustrates the join I have made.

[image: Join between OCRD and LANG]

Based on the join already performed by Crystal Reports I want to create a formula which performs the following action:

```
select LocalisedText from LANG where Identifier = 1;
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this with a formula. Is a formula even sufficient for solving my issue?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need formula what you need is adding the below code in `Record Selection Formula`

Go to `Report -> selection Formula -> Record` and write below code:

```
Identifier = 1;
```

and place the `LocalisedText` in details

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I am still a beginner. How can i place `LocalisedText` in the detail field and how can I add the result field to my report. A tutorial link or so would be great.

Comment: It is just a drag and drop part of the field on to the details section from field explorer.. There are lof of manuals available for developing the crystal reports.. you can follow any of them as per your requirement..I would suggest you to start development and learn the crystal reports by clarifying your queries